# c# group by first word

Tags: c#, linq

I have this list:

```
 var items = new List<Model>
            {
                new Model { Id = 1, Name = "first item (a)" },
                new Model { Id = 2, Name = "first item (b)" },
                new Model { Id = 3, Name = "first item (c)" },
                new Model { Id = 4, Name = "second item (a)" },
                new Model { Id = 5, Name = "second item (b)" },
                new Model { Id = 6, Name = "second item (c)" },
                new Model { Id = 7, Name = "third item (a)" },
                new Model { Id = 8, Name = "third item (b)" },
                new Model { Id = 9, Name = "third item (c)" },
            };
```

How can I group all items that the name starts with the same word, for example, I need a list of all items that begins with "first" and a list of all items that begin with "second" etc.

Thanks

Comment: Is the list limited to exactly what you have shown here? Or are there other ways of writing this as well like `the fourth item (aaa)` or `4th item (abd)`. Without knowing all of the data constraints it is difficult to formulate a regular expression or string parsing rules.

Comment: Is it possible to change the data model to more effectively meet the needs of the system?  Even just having a read-only property that dynamically returns the value you're looking for parsed from `Name` would be pretty helpful here.  Aside from that, what have you tried and what didn't work?  `.GroupBy()` sounds like the ideal place to start.

Comment: @Igor it's not limited to this example, it can be all kinds of values the user is entering.
the key thing is, I want to group all items that the name starts with the same word, thanks

Comment: Try something like `var groups = from item in items let firstWord = item.Name.Split(' ')[0] group item by firstWord into g select g;`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you want to group the items by the first "word", separated by spaces?

Use

```
items.GroupBy(i => i.Name.Split()[0])
```

Answer (score 1):

So you have a sequence of `Models`, where every Model has an Id and a string property `Name`

> How can I group all items that the name starts with the same word

Apparently you have to introduce to class Model the idea of `Word`, or maybe `First Word`.

### Define Word

You haven't defined `Word`. Is the delimiter only a space? or is it any white space character, inclusive `\r` and `\n`? And what do you want if you have two spaces:

```
"Word1  Word2"
```

Do you have two Words? or maybe three, an empty word between the two spaces?

### Write an extension method

Of course you are a good programmer, so you want to create reusable code, that is maintainable, easy to understand. It would be nice if you can unit test it.

If in the near future someone says: you didn't support `\r\n` until now, but we need to support it now, you don't want to check all code to find out where someone tried to find the first word of the name of the model.

Consider to write some extension methods for class `Model`. If you are not familiar with extension methods, read [Extension Methods Demystified](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/csharp/csharp-extension-method)

After you've written the extension methods, you can write the following:

```
Model model = ...
string firstWord = model.GetFirstWord();
```

So let's extend!

```
public static char[] WordSeparators {get} = new [] {' ', '\t', '.', ',', ...};

public IEnumerable<string> SplitName(this Model model)
{
    return model.Name.Split(WordSeparators);
}
```

This is a fast method, especially if you have only a few word separators. Another method would be to use regular expressions with "s" to indicate a white space. But that is too long for an answer.

```
public string GetFirstWord(this Model model)
{
    return model.SplitName().FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Simple code, easy to understand, easy to use, maintain and good to unit test.

### Back to your question

> How can I group all items that the name starts with the same word

After you've created `GetFirstWord` the code is a one-liner:

```
IEnumerable<Model> models = ...
var groupOfModelsThatStartWithSameWord = models.GroupBy(model => model.GetFirstWord());
```

In words: from every model, in the sequence of models, get the first word. Make groups of models, where every group is a sequence of Models that have the same first word, while the `Key` of the group is this common first word.